# JCS 1.3 - pre-load cache from disk

Tags: caching, jcs

I am using Indexed disk cache and JCS 1.3. When I restart, the JCS cache does not seem to pre-load data, instead it does lazy initialization of the cache.

On startup, the stats are as below:

```
Region Name = triplet_set_1
HitCountRam = 0
HitCountAux = 0
---------------------------LRU Memory Cache
List Size = 0
Map Size = 0
Put Count = 0
Hit Count = 0
Miss Count = 0
---------------------------Indexed Disk Cache
Is Alive = true
Key Map Size = 138832
Data File Length = 72470304
Hit Count = 0
Bytes Free = 0
Optimize Operation Count = 1
Times Optimized = 0
Recycle Count = 0
Recycle Bin Size = 0
Startup Size = 138832
Purgatory Hits = 0
Purgatory Size = 0
Working = true
Alive = false
Empty = true
Size = 0
Region Name = triplet_set_1
HitCountRam = 200
HitCountAux = 100
```

I was hoping to see a high map size given the fact that data file length is significant.

Thanks a lot